# I now get the message "monero-core" is not responding

Tags: linux, update, monero-core

I applied the update monero.gui.0.16.0.3 from monero.gui.v0.16.0.2 on Zorin 15.2 and followed the instructions for a new installation
from your website.

Comment: Have you already tried rebooting your system?

Comment: I have rebooted numerous times, added shared library files etc.

Comment: Does GUI v0.16.0.2 still work properly? Also, do you see any errors in `monero-wallet-gui.log`?

Comment: No, I tried that and it gives me the same message. Where can I find the monero-wallet-gui.log ?

Comment: Did any Monero version work properly on your system or is this the first time you are trying to run Monero? `monero-wallet-gui.log` should be in the same directory as `monero-wallet-gui`. If not, I'd recommend simply searching the system for the file.

Comment: Thanks, This is a new Zorin installation and I battled to get GUI.0.16.0.2 going. After the upgrade to GUI0.16.0.3 none of them are working. There is no log file anywhere, I made the hidden files visible.

Comment: Can you check if `monerod` works properly? You should be able to start it manually / separately via `./monerod` (from the terminal in the same directory as `monerod`).

Comment: I have never been able to start from monerod or monero-wallet even when it worked. I found the log file and it warns me about the frontend and it detected a binding loop for property "implicit-Width". I hope it means something to you. deBruyne.

Comment: What kind of error message is displayed if you try to run `monerod` from the terminal?

Comment: When I do that it tries to synchronize. When I try wallet-GUI it gives me Date Time 938 W app startd (login info) Date Time 949 W Qt::5.9.7 GUI:0.16.0.3-3c69024 | screen: 1024x768 - dpi 96 - ratio : 0.635 It reduces my screen a little then stops. Thank you for your time deBruyne.

Comment: Can you try starting the GUI as follows? `QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-wallet-gui`

Comment: Thanks DeBruyne, that worked first time. Still don't know what I did wrong. Do I have to start it like that every time ?

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I can see, you did nothing wrong. However, your system is not able to handle the default graphic mode of the GUI. `QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext` is basically a fallback mode with respect to graphics. Yes, you will have to use that command every time you start the GUI. Do you know how to write a brief script for it?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to write a script for it. Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the script you wrote, I found it yesterday under one of my other icons. It works but somehow connects to another wallet-GUI that does recognise me. I don't know which files are used. I made a hardcopy of the script and it looks perfect to me. Thus I will use the script you gave me previously, that works fine.

Comment: Which script specifically are you referring to? I suppose we could adjust that to add the `QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext` environment variable.

Comment: I suppose I can try that, I made it writeable in properties. Exec=/home/theob/Monero/monero-wallet-gui %u Thanks

Comment: Can you please state to which specific script you are referring? Alternatively, upload the content to a pastebin (e.g. paste.debian.net). Then we can try to adjust it to include the environment variable. Otherwise, it will be quite difficult to assist you.

Comment: Thanks, but I am fine the way I am. I thought the script came from you. I certainly didn't create it. The only programming I did was with Quickbasic  4.5, and that was a long time ago.

Comment: All right and you're welcome. There is a script included in the GUI binaries, but I didn't write it.

Comment: P.S. If you do not mind, please mark my answer as satisfactory for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by starting the GUI as follows:

`QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-wallet-gui`

QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext is basically a fallback mode with respect to graphics. It can be utilized in case the 'default graphics' do not properly support the rendering of the GUI.